# Creating a video game in Maya for android

Tags: maya

I recently installed Maya for creating video games, and was wondering something. Can I create games in Maya, and run it on mobile devices?

Comment: I didn't think Maya was a gaming engine. Maya creates graphics, that are added to games. You need to either code the game in a native language, or something like Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.

Maya is a character animation software, not a game development platform. It doesn't directly support creating an application of any kind. Maya creates a portion of the raw materials for a game, but you'll need some kind of programming tool to create the actual game itself.

Comment: Okay, also which software can I use to create games for the iphone or any mobile device?

Comment: It depends on what programming languages you know (if any) and what kind of game you want to create. Since you asked about Maya, I assume you want to create a 3D game. [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) is one of the most popular ways to do that (beyond just native code on each kind of device). 3D games in particular are not trivial to create.

For a simpler app / 2D game, the easiest way might be with [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), which allows you to build your app with HTML and JavaScript and then package it for mobile platforms.